# How to re-update a date to a different format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, format

I have a column in which it stores date value. However, some how the dates were populated in the wrong format. The date format of the column is `DD/MM/YYYY`, however the date was populated as `MM/DD/YYYY`. How can I change the value from `MM/DD/YYYY` to `DD/MM/YYYY`? E.g. At this moment, it is showing `03/05/2012` and it is read as `3rd May 2012` whereby it really should really have been populated as `05/03/2012` (`5th March 2012`).

The above has been solved, but I have a similar question:
How can I flip "2012-12-01 12:33:00.0" to become "2012-01-12 12:33:00.0"? I had tried "select convert(varchar(50), convert(datetime, log_date, 103), 121)" and used both 101 and 103 and still not able to flip it.

Comment: If the type of the column is `date`, `datetime` or `datetime2`, it doesn't *have* a format. Also - are *all* of the dates "stored" incorrectly? If not, how are we to distinguish dates that need flipping and those that do not?

Comment: Hi Damien. It is easy to determine which date needs flipping. The date column shouldn't be greater than the current date.

Comment: But is 01/03/2012 the 3rd of January or the 1st of March? Both are in the past.

Comment: That's something that I can't correct and have to look case by case, but I do not want the problem to grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`convert` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to convert between strings and datetime values.

```
Convert a DD/MM/YYYY string to a datetime: convert(datetime, value, 103)
Convert a datetime to a DD/MM/YYYY string: convert(varchar(10), value, 103)
Convert a MM/DD/YYYY string to a datetime: convert(datetime, value, 101)
Convert a datetime to a MM/DD/YYYY string: convert(varchar(10), value,  101)
```

Which of these you need depends on whether you have stored the dates as varchar or datetime in the table.

Comment: I want to convert MM/DD/YYYY value to DD/MM/YYYY value.

Comment: @cooldude: Then you use the third to convert the string to a datetime value, then the second to convert the datetime value to a string: `convert(varchar(10), convert(datetime, value, 101), 103)`.

Comment: Thanks! This works. May I know what other parameter are there beside 101 and 103? What is the format for YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss.mmm and YYYY-DD-MM hh:mi:ss.mmm?

Comment: Thanks Guffa. I had solved this problem. But I have a similar problem in another database. This time, the dateformat is in YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss.mmm. E.g. How can I flip "2012-12-01 12:33:00.0" to become "2012-01-12 12:33:00.0"? I had tried to use your solution, but the time portion is gone after the CONVERT.

Comment: @cooldude: You need more space in the string, use `varchar(21)` instead of `varchar(10)`.

Comment: I had already changed it to varchar(100) previously but it is still returning me without the time portion. Also, what parameter should I use instead of 101 and 103?

Comment: I look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx and it tells me I should 121 for YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss.mmm format, but how can I flip it?

I had tried select convert(varchar(50), convert(datetime, log_date, 103), 121) and used both 101 and 103 and still not able to flip it.

Comment: @cooldude: There is no support for a YYYY-DD-MM format, because noone uses it. If you somehow have that in your database, you have to use string operations to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how the date is coming in to your column. But the convert function might help here:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '03/05/2012',103)
```

You might look at this msdn article for the different date and time styles:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx

Hope this helps.

btw: if the problem is only how it is stored in the table itself you should have a look at your cultur setting. here you find the dateformat of the different sys languages:

```
select * from sys.syslanguages
```

Comment: The wrong dates were populated wrongly from an excel file. That's why I am now cleaning them up. I will take a look of your convert function to see if it helps.

Comment: Hi, I had used the convert function but it doesn't help. Actually what I want to do is to perform UPDATE on those bad data. I want to convert the existing value of 03/05/2012 to 05/03/2012

Answer (score 0):

The date is stored as a point in time but not as a special style. How it is returned to you may depend on language/culture settings of your database.

I think you can use SELECT [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)(...) to get whatever format you want. Here are some examples: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: Hi, I had used the convert function but it doesn't help. Actually what I want to do is to perform UPDATE on those bad data. I want to convert the existing value of 03/05/2012 to 05/03/2012

Comment: @cooldude I agree with the comments by Damien_The_Unbeliever below your question. If the column is in date type, the data in this column in fact doesn't have a format itself, so it is not necessary for you to try converting the values. The issue is only about how the database presents the data when returning.

Comment: @cooldude I don't know whether this is useful for you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/11/13/how-to-change-date-format-after-installing-sql-server.aspx

Comment: I have so many date fields in the table. Say, date1 and date2 columns. Only date1 is showing in the wrong format. But date2 is in the right format. If I change how the database presents the data when returning, it will affect all my date fields.